# How do I get the index of the smallest element in a double array?

Tags: java

How do I get the index of the smallest element in a double array,`double[]`, in Java ?

Comment: no it is necessary for my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shorter to give you the code.

```
public int minIndex(double... ds) {
    int idx = -1;
    double d= Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    for(int i = 0; i < ds.length; i++)
        if(ds[i] < d) {
            d = ds[i];
            idx = i;
        }
    return idx;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You iterate over the array, comparing the different elements, always storing the value and index of the smallest one for comparison and retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the lowest value seen so far, and the index of that value.

Look through the array, and if the value at that point is lower then use that value as the lowest from now on, and update the index held.